# How to find the value in a list at which a maximum value of a function occurs

Tags: f#

I want to find not just the maximum value of a function applied to a list (for which I would just use List.maxBy) but also the value in the list this occurred at. This feels like a fairly common operation and given the richness of the F# libraries in general I wouldn't be at all surprised to discover it was actually already available but I cannot seem to find it if it is!

To illustrate with an example, I want to be able to map a list `domain` and a function `f`

```
let domain = [0 .. 5]
let f x = -x * (x - 2)
```

to `(1, 1)` (since the function applied to an other element of the list is less than 1).

I first tried this:

```
let findMaximum domain f =
    let candidates = [ for x in domain do
                        yield x, f x ]
    let rec findMaximumHelper domain f currentMax =
        match domain with
        | [] -> currentMax
        | head::tail -> 
            let cand = f head
            match currentMax with
            | None ->
                let newMax = Some(head, cand)
                findMaximumHelper tail f newMax
            | Some(maxAt, possMax) ->
                let newMax =
                    if cand > possMax then Some(head, cand)
                    else Some(maxAt, possMax)
                findMaximumHelper tail f newMax
    findMaximumHelper domain f None

let answer = findMaximum domain f
```

at which point I realised this is very close to a *fold* operation, and put together

```
let findMaximum2 domain f =
    let findMaximumHelper f acc x =
        let cand = f x
        match acc with
        | None -> Some(x, cand)
        | Some(maxAt, possMax) ->
            if cand > possMax then Some(x, cand)
            else Some(maxAt, possMax)
    List.fold (findMaximumHelper f) None domain

let answer2 = findMaximum2 domain f
```

instead.

My question is, are these idiomatic F# ways of solving this problem, or indeed, is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. `List.maxBy` *already* returns the value in the list, not the return value of the projection function. Or was that simply a strange phrasing for saying you want both?

Comment: Thanks @ildjarn, you're quite right – I wasn't so much after the pair (x, f x) as the value x. My mistake here was the poor choice of an example where these values happen to coincide, plus seeing a wrong example online which led me to believe that List.maxBy returned the maximum value after the function had been applied (i.e. did list |> List.map f |> List.max). The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340331.aspx) is quite clear on the subject so I haven't really got any excuses!

Comment: Ah, no worries. It just made your question confusing since the builtin functionality already did what you were asking for :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, the F# library provides all the necessary higher order functions to express this succinctly:

```
domain
|> Seq.map (fun x -> x, f x)
|> Seq.maxBy snd
```

**Note:** updated to use `Seq.map` and `Seq.maxBy` instead of `List.map` and `List.maxBy` to address @ildjarn's concern about creating an unnecessary intermediate list.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Stephen's answer, that avoids creating a second `List`, with the tradeoff of executing `f` one extra time:

```
domain
|> List.maxBy f
|> fun x -> x, f x
```