# Finding an index of a max value of a list in F#

Tags: f#, max

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list for example

```
let list = [5;23;29;1] 
let x = max list // This will return 2 because 29 will be the max value and it's "indexed" at position 2
```

I'm not sure about how to go about writing the `max` function

Since my list will only contain four elements I currently have some code like this

```
let list = (1, newMap1 |> getScore) :: (2, newMap2 |> getScore) :: (3, newMap3 |> getScore) :: (4, newMap4 |> getScore) :: []
```

I consider this a terrible approach but I'm still stuck on how to return `(x, _)` after I find the max of `(_, y)`. I'm very confident with imperative approaches but  I'm stumped on how to do this functionally

Comment: The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591062/finding-an-index-of-a-max-value-of-a-list-in-f will provide a hint about what you need

Comment: Is this supposed to mean recursion or did you just accidentally provide a link to my own post.

Comment: Sorry, meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759993/how-to-find-the-value-in-a-list-at-which-a-maximum-value-of-a-function-occurs?rq=1

Comment: Damn, if it was the former I'd say that was a genius idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to do this. At the low-level, you can write a recursive function to iterate and pattern match over a list. This is good exercise if you are learning F#.

Similarly, you can implement this using the `fold` function. Here, the idea is that we keep some state, consisting of the "best value" and the index of the best value. At each step, we either keep the original information, or update it:

```
let _, maxValue, maxIndex = 
  list |> List.fold (fun (index, maxSoFar, maxIndex) v -> 
    if v > maxSoFar then (index+1, v, index+1)
    else (index+1, maxSoFar, maxIndex)) (-1, System.Int32.MinValue, -1)
```

Finally, the shortest option I can think of is to use `mapi` and `maxBy` functions:

```
list
|> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
|> Seq.maxBy snd
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to give me the right answer but I'm trying to figure out how it works... haha.

Comment: Nice and informative answer - I didn't think of all of the different ways of doing it. =)

Comment: Instead of Seq.mapi you can also use Seq.indexed - a tad more concise :)

Comment: @Kevin Oh nice, I need to learn all these new fancy functions :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer only using pattern matching and recursion.

```
let list = [5;23;29;1] 

let rec findIndexOfMaxValue (maxValue:int) indexOfMaxValue currentIndex aList = 
    match aList with
    | [] -> indexOfMaxValue                                                            
    | head::tail -> match head with
                    | head when head > maxValue ->  findIndexOfMaxValue head currentIndex (currentIndex + 1) tail
                    | _ -> findIndexOfMaxValue maxValue indexOfMaxValue (currentIndex + 1) tail

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let indexOfMaxValue = findIndexOfMaxValue 0 0 0 list
    printfn "The index of the maximum value is %A." indexOfMaxValue
    //The index of the maximum value is 2.

    0
```

Out of interest, I made a timing script comparing my algorithm with the other ones provided:

```
open System.Diagnostics

let n = 5000
let random = System.Random 543252

let randomlists = 
  [for i in [1..n] -> [ for i in [1..n] -> random.Next (0, n*n)]]


let stopWatch = 
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  sw

let timeIt (name : string) (a : int list -> 'T) : unit = 
  let t = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
  let v = a (randomlists.[0])
  for i = 1 to (n - 1) do
    a randomlists.[i] |> ignore
  let d = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds - t
  printfn "%s, elapsed %d ms, result %A" name d v


let rec findIndexOfMaxValue (maxValue:int) indexOfMaxValue currentIndex aList = 
        match aList with
        | [] -> indexOfMaxValue                                                            
        | head::tail -> match head with
                        | head when head > maxValue ->  findIndexOfMaxValue head currentIndex (currentIndex + 1) tail
                        | _ -> findIndexOfMaxValue maxValue indexOfMaxValue (currentIndex + 1) tail

let findIndexOfMaxValueFoldAlg list =
    let _, maxValue, maxIndex  = 
       list |> List.fold (fun (index, maxSoFar, maxIndex) v -> 
        if v > maxSoFar then (index+1, v, index+1)
        else (index+1, maxSoFar, maxIndex)) (-1, System.Int32.MinValue, -1)
    maxIndex

let findIndexOfMaxValueSimpleSeq list = list
                                        |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
                                        |> Seq.maxBy snd
                                        |> fst
let findIndexOfMaxValueSimpleList list =
        list
        |> List.mapi (fun i x -> i, x)
        |> List.maxBy snd
        |> fst
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    timeIt "recursiveOnly" (findIndexOfMaxValue 0 0 0)
    timeIt "simpleSeq" findIndexOfMaxValueSimpleSeq
    timeIt "simpleList" findIndexOfMaxValueSimpleList
    0
```

The results I get are:

```
recursiveOnly, elapsed 356ms, result 3562
foldAlgorithm, elapsed 1602ms, result 3562
simpleSeq, elapsed 4504ms, result 3562
simpleList, elapsed 4395ms, result 3562
```

Answer (score 2):

I have these functions in my helper library:

```
module List =
    let maxIndexBy projection list =
        list
        |> List.mapi (fun i x -> i, projection x)
        |> List.maxBy snd
        |> fst

    let maxIndex list = maxIndexBy id list
```

Returns the index of the max element, optionally using a given projection function. You can write the same functions for the Seq and Array modules easily by replacing the "List" part and renaming the arguments.